# How to transform "X hours/days ago" into standard date time

Tags: r, datetime, as.date

I have scraped news data, including time in form of:

```
time <- c("11 hours ago", "2 days ago", "3 days ago")
```

How can I translate this into a standard date time format? BTW: I assume that for intra-day differences (e.g. "11 hours ago") the browser recognizes my system time? Since news come from around the globe.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `seq` when removing the `ago` and adding in front a `-`. This will work for times given as `sec`, `min`, `hour`, `day`, `DSTday`, `week`, `month`, `quarter` or `year`.

```
lapply(sub(" ago", "", time), function(x) seq(Sys.time(), by=paste0("-", x),
 length.out = 2)[2])
#[[1]]
#[1] "2021-08-29 23:41:26 CEST"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "2021-08-28 10:41:26 CEST"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "2021-08-27 10:41:26 CEST"
```

To get a vector use `c` with `do.call`:

```
do.call(c, lapply(sub(" ago", "", time), function(x) seq(Sys.time(),
  by=paste0("-",x), length.out = 2)[2]))
#[1] "2021-08-30 00:11:15 CEST" "2021-08-28 11:11:15 CEST"
#[3] "2021-08-27 11:11:15 CEST"
```

Comment: Great option for multiple time inputs and flexible on either list or vector output. I had to transform another time format "minutes" into "min" or "mins" first.

Comment: You can try `time <- sub("minutes", "min", time)` to convert `minutes` into `min`.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have hours and days as units of time, then,

```
Sys.time() - ifelse(grepl('hours', time), 
                   as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', time)) * 3600, 
                               as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', time)) * 24 * 3600)

#[1] "2021-08-30 00:31:32 +03" "2021-08-28 11:31:32 +03" "2021-08-27 11:31:32 +03"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the easiest way that I can store it in a column of my dataframe instead handling a list in between.

Answer (score 0):

a lubridate solution;

```
library(lubridate)
    
time <- c("11 hours ago", "2 days ago", "3 days ago")

time_numeric <- as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", time))
time_logical <- ifelse(grepl('hour',time),'hour',ifelse(grepl('day',time),'day','unnknown'))

time_tidy <- data.frame(diff=time_numeric,type=time_logical)

current_time <- Sys.time()

time_tidy$new <- as_datetime(ifelse(time_tidy$type=='hour',current_time-hours(time_tidy$diff),ifelse(time_tidy$type=='day',current_time-days(time_tidy$diff),current_time)))

time_tidy$new
```

**output;**

```
[1] "2021-08-30 00:29:21 +03"
[1] "2021-08-28 11:29:21 +03"
[1] "2021-08-27 11:29:21 +03"
```

Comment: This is not scalable. Imagine a vector with 1000 elements and you manually having to specify `days` or `hours`